# Efficiently keeping a string appended with another string

Tags: objective-c

I have some code like this:

```
-(void)updateString: (NSString*)str {
     self.buffer = [self.buffer stringByAppendingString:str];
     self.string = [self.buffer stringByAppendingString:@"Always at the end of self.string"];
}
```

Input:

```
self.buffer: "blah\n"
self.string: "Always at the end of self.string"
str: "Hello\n"
```

Output:

```
self.buffer: "blah\nHello\n"
self.string: "blah\nHello\nAlways at the end of self.string"
```

If `updateString` is called very often, will it cause a performance issue as `self.buffer` becomes larger and larger? It seems like this will suffer from inefficiencies similar to the [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm).

If so, what can I do to improve my naive implementation? Use `NSMutableString` for `self.buffer`?

Comment: NSMutableString is the way to go.  Simple and efficient, and arguably not "premature optimization", since it's simpler to use in some contexts than the non-mutable string approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSMutableString will be more efficient with large strings because it wont need to copy the data each time.

You should do profiling with instruments and see what happens. Paint away, and then worry about this issue when you see updateString at the top of your CPU optimization hitlist in instruments.
Also, without profiling, it's tricky to predict where things will need to be optimized. For instance, if updateString is called much more than self.string you could optimize this way:

```
//assuming NSMutableString *buffer;

- (void)updateString:(NSString *)string {
    [self.buffer appendString:string];
}

- (NSString *)string {
    return [self.buffer stringByAppendingString:@"Always at the end of self.string"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you even need separate `buffer` and `string` properties?  Can you just use a single `NSMutableString`, and overwrite the “always-at-the-end” part when you append more text?

```
- (void)updateStringWithString:(NSString *)moreText {
    static NSString *const tail = @"Always at the end";
    NSRange rangeToReplace = NSMakeRange(self.string.length - tail.length, tail.length);
    [self.string replaceCharactersInRange:rangeToReplace withString:moreText];
    [self.string appendString:tail];
}
```